# Dynamic Facebook cover

Tags: php, facebook, url, dynamic

I want to be able to add a personalised URL, and individual's name to a generic Facebook cover design

I want to create a personalised FB cover for my many users

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: If I get it right, and you are trying to add text to a image with php, take a look at image magick's php lib: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: I need to be able to take a flat image, add a layer of text pulled in from my user's profiles, then flatten and output and save as a jpg for the user then to upload to FB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to simply write text to an image, you can use PHP's lib image magick.

For instance, you can try this function on an image object:

```
bool Imagick::annotateImage ( ImagickDraw $draw_settings , float $x , float $y , float $angle , string $text )
```

As you can see it takes some settings (color I guess), the position, an angle and a string and prints the text into the image given the other parameters.

More information about the method can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php). How to use image magick, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). AFAIR you needed to add the plugin to your php config file and then just require it on the code. Then you need to convert your jpg file to an image magick's image object; use [readImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php) function:

```
bool Imagick::readImage ( string $filename )
```

Or something along those lines. And finally add the text and save (there shoudl be a writeImage as well). Shouldn't be too complicated if you have the right tools.